# Identity theorem - holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be holomorphic functions on some connected open set $D\subset\mathbb{C}$. Then if set $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : f(z)=g(z) \}$ has limit point in $D$, then $f\equiv g$ on $D$. But what if $D$ is disconnected? Then theorem won't hold unless such limit point exists in all connected components of $D$? Am I right?

Comment: Right. For a counterexample when $D$ is disconnected, let $f(z)\equiv 1$, and let $g$ be equal to $1$ on one component but zero on all the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. The identity theorem on a open set $\Omega$ is the following : if $f=g$ on a set $A$ which has an accumulation point $z \in \Omega$, then $f \equiv g$ on the connected component of $\Omega$ which contains $z$.